# Distance from a point to a set in $\mathbb{R}$

Tags: real-analysis

I studied physics along time ago but (to my regret) never really spent time on and therefore never really understood the rigor (and beauty!) of real analysis. I am trying to make up for lost knowledge and time now and have picked up a book on introductory real analysis.

I have a question on distance between a point and a non-empty set $X \subset \mathbb{R}$.

First of all, let $b \in \mathbb{R}$ and define the distance between $b$ and $X$ as
$$
d(b,X) = \inf_{x\in X} \,\,\lvert b-x \rvert
$$

Now, let $X = (a,b)$, then $b = \sup X$ and so $d(b,X) = 0$.

Next, define the closed interval $Y = [b,b] = {b}$. Since $Y$ is a closed interval, $d(x,Y) = d(x,b) \neq 0 \, \forall x \in X$, because for a closed interval $d(x,Y) = 0 \Rightarrow x \in Y$.

To me, saying $d(x,Y) = d(x,b) \neq 0 \, \forall x \in X$, seems equivalent to saying that $d(X,b) \neq 0$. Clearly  I am missing something because there appears to be a contradiction here, but not sure where I made the mistake?

Comment: If $0\le x<\epsilon \;\forall \epsilon>0$ then $x=0$

Comment: the idea is the inf of a set, is not necessarily in the set. for example: $inf\left(\left\{ \dfrac{1}{n}|n\in N\right\} \right)=0$. so even if the distance to each point in X is positive, the inf of the distances can still be 0

Comment: @J.W.Tanner  Sorry, I don't understand what you mean. You agree that if an element is not in a closed interval then the distance from that element to the closed set is not zero? What I find puzzling is that if the closed interval is a single element and equal to the supremum of an open set then the distance from that open set to the closed interval is zero.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is you aren't using the definition of infinimum, which is not necessarily the minimum. I will show you the contradiction in your logic.

Suppose $d(X,b)=\inf_{x\in X}d(x,b)>0$. Choose $\epsilon>0$ so that $0<d(X,b)-\epsilon<d(X,b)$. Then since $d(X,b)-\epsilon$ is a lower bound for the set $A:=\{d(x,b):\, x\in X\}$ and is not the infinimum, it follows that $d(x,b)>d(X,b)-\epsilon$ for all $x\in X$. But since $b$ is a limit point of $X$, most certainly you can find $x\in X$ with $d(x,b)<d(X,b)-\epsilon$. Hence, a contradiction.

You need practice playing around with the definition of infinimum.

Comment: Yes, thanks. I understand the that $d(X,b) = 0$. But my mistake is that because $d(Y,x) > 0$, where the closed interval $Y = [b,b] = {b}$ and $x \in X$ it does not mean that the distance between the **sets** $X$ and $Y$ is zero. For that I have to take the infimum again, which then gives zero and hence no contradiction.

Comment: I'm not sure what the question is.  The short and sweet of it is that if $d(x,Y)>0$ for all $X$, it is impossible for the minimum, if it exists, of $d(x,Y)=0$. This is true since $d(x,b)$ has no minimum. However, the infinimum (which does exist) can equal $0$.